# Бесконечный скроллинг

Tags: javascript

Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать бесконечный скроллинг для сайта, как на фейсбуке и твиттере. Помогите, пожалуйста. То есть надо, чтобы человек скроллил вниз, у него появлялась картинка о загрузке, и cразу подгружался контент, при том всё это на javascript?

Comment: Спасибо за разрешение.

Comment: интересно, а что произойдёт если посмотреть код, не получив разрешения?

Comment: По-теме: Просто догружаешь данные динамически с помощью ajax, генерируешь html-элементы, добавляешь в конец страницы. Ну а пока грузится ajax можно вставить элемент изображающий загрузку.

В каком месте проблемы?

Comment: бесконечный скролл - зло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то делал такое, говнокод конечно же, но я тогда учился только

```
    setInterval('scroll();', 250); // Вместо onscroll используем таймер, так как некоторые браузеры немного подвисают
    var next = "2", loading = false; // Объявляем переменные next - страница, котору нам надо загрузить, loading во время подгрузки true

    function scroll() {
        if (loading) return; // если уже грузится останавливаем функцию
        if (window.pageYOffset > (document.body.offsetHeight - 3500)) { // если скролл ниже высота_страницы - 3500, то 
            load_feed(next); // запускаем функцию загрузки, передавая переменную page
        }
    }

    function load_feed(m) {
        if (!m) return; // если не передана страница, которую надо загрузить или она ложь, то останавливаем
        loading = true; // говорим, что пошла загрузка
        $("#feed_" + m).html('<center>Загрузка...</center>'); // пишем загрузку
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax/feed.php?page=" + m, // ajax запрос
            success: function (r) { // если все хорошо, то сервер должен вернуть JSON {html:"код подгружаемого кусочка", next:"номер следующей страницы"}
                eval('s=' + r + ';'); // превращаем этот ответ сервера в объект
                $("#feed_" + m).html(s.html); // вставляем этот кусок
                if (s.error) return console.log(s.error); // если сервер вернул ошибку, пишем в консоль (в моем случаи это {error:"Описание ошибки"})
                next = s.next; // изменяем значение следующей страницы
                loading = false; // говорим, что ничего уже не грузится
            }
        });
    }

    html:
    <div id="feed_2"></div>

Примечания: в конце подгружаемого кусочка должен быть <div id="feed_(номер следующей страницы)"></div>, 3500 самый оптимальный вариант, для текста, поскольку пользователю почти не приходится ждать, но если используются тетрис из изображений, например галерея или каталог товаров, то лучше это уменьшить до 500..1000
```

Comment: Раз говнокод, так зачем выкладывали? Говнокодеров плодить?

Comment: Почему сразу плодить, просто принцип работы показать. Если немного переделать, например убрать все в одну функцию, то вполне даже годный вариант может получится.

Answer (score 0):

ищите в гугле, вот первая же [ссылка](http://bykov.su/entries/beskonechnaya-stranitsa-na-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

Вот небольшой [примерчик](http://jsbin.com/ilevux/5/watch)  набрасал.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте через ajax.
[Подгрузка странички](http://habrahabr.ru/post/128552/)